# Regex pattern to split the string based on numeric characters

Tags: python, regex, string, alphanumeric

I'd like to have a regex pattern that splits the string based on the numbers present in them

```
50cushions => [50,cushions]
30peoplerescued20children => [30,peoplerescued,20,children]
moon25flightin2days => [moon,25,flightin,2,days]
```

Is it possible to do this a regex, or else what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> re.findall(r'\d+|\D+', '50cushions')
['50', 'cushions']
>>> re.findall(r'\d+|\D+', '30peoplerescued20children')
['30', 'peoplerescued', '20', 'children']
>>> re.findall(r'\d+|\D+', 'moon25flightin2days')
['moon', '25', 'flightin', '2', 'days']
```

where `\d+` matches one or more digits and `\D+` matches one or more non digits. `\d+|\D+` will find either (`|`) a group of digits or non digits, and append the result to the list of matches.

Or with `itertools`

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby('moon25flightin2days', key=str.isdigit)]
['moon', '25', 'flightin', '2', 'days']
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain a bit about the pattern.

Comment: @coding_pleasures it looks for a sequence of digits `\d` OR non digits `\D` and then captures that sequence, looking across the whole string.